# Can I send requests to app with devise without credentials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, devise

I have backend app with devise and a ionic app from which I make requests to backend.
 
Whenever I send requests, gets me 401 status unauthorized.
In this project I've already doorkeeper to manage authorization, so I don't rly need authorization from devise.
 Can I somehow make these requests( add something to headers ) always authorized without sending post request with credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify the user somehow. If you're not using a session, you'll need to generate some kind of access token, which Doorkeeper can do for you. I'm not sure if this is helpful or not, but I set up the following flow recently.

One option when using OAuth2 through a trusted client, e.g. a front-end app you build/distribute yourself, is the *Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant*. Doorkeeper has a [guide in the docs](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-flow) for this with advice on dealing with Devise.

I ended up with something like this in my Doorkeeper initializer. You don't need to authorize the client, because you trust it:

```
resource_owner_from_credentials do |routes|
  request.params[:user] = {:email => request.params[:email], :password => request.params[:password]}
  request.env['devise.allow_params_authentication'] = true
  request.env['warden'].authenticate!(:scope => :user)
end

skip_authorization do |resource_owner|
  true
end
```

Then you should be able to send a request using the password grant type as follows (also shown in the docs).

```
RestClient.post 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/token', {grant_type: 'password', email: 'email@gmail.com', password: 'password'}, {:accept => 'application/json'}
```

You should receive the same JSON back as shown in the docs.

```
{
  "access_token": "1f0af717251950dbd4d73154fdf0a474a5c5119adad999683f5b450c460726aa",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 7200
}
```

Now you have a way of identifying your user. You just attach this token to each request to endpoints protected by `doorkeeper_for`.

```
RestClient.get 'http://localhost/api/v1/users', { 'Authorization' => 'Bearer 1f0af717251950dbd4d73154fdf0a474a5c5119adad999683f5b450c460726aa', :accept => 'application/json'}
```

Comment: Maybe it could work, but there's a little bit more difficulty. Cause in backend app, there's authentication on the beginning like this:
`before_action :authenticate_user!`
But on the frontend app, there's authentication on concrete parts of app you want to access. And when you try to request some data from frontend, you get an error, cause u're not authenticated.

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at the example Doorkeeper/Devise app (https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-provider-app). It authenticates with Devise through Doorkeeper, rather than with `authenticate_user !`.

Comment: Well in the end, I think its better to leave only one authentication system, because both devise and doorkeeper'll do unnecessary complexity. And now the question is how better to do it with doorkeeper, but that's another story :)